# epplus adds unwanted decimal places when getting text values

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using eppplus to read some values from a spreadsheet but it seems to add some decimal places even with no formatting on the cell.  For example doing

```
string value = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Text // value on spreadsheet is 1000
```

puts 1,000.00 into value.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: `value = Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString("0.#");` is a dirty fix I believe.

Comment: yep, the dirty hack worked!  Cheers, will refactor if anybody can provide the proper solution or explain why epplus is adding formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Text` returns the formatted value. You have to use `worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value`